# ConnectApi.ConnectApiException : commerce.exception.CommerceException: Error fetching Promotions Associated to this Cart

Tags: b2b-commerce

I am having an issue in my sandbox that is already upgraded to the Winter 22 (api 53) which I will have to fix before it is deployed into the production instance (In October).

Basically (B2B Commerce)

```
ConnectApi.CommerceCart.addItemToCart(webstoreId, effectiveAccountId, cartId, cartItemInput);
```

is failing with the following error :

> ConnectApi.ConnectApiException : commerce.exception.CommerceException: Error fetching Promotions Associated to this Cart

This is happening on a product which is used for discounts and has a negative List Price.
It was working fine until now. I think the negative list price is the problem as it works if I change the List price to a positive value, but all the logic (and orders history) is based on this negative value so I would like to keep it that way. I can not find any documentation on this error, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best regards,
Julien

Comment: If you don't get any answers here, I'd recommend creating a case and posting a question in the B2B Commerce Trailblazers group: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/groups/0F93A000000HWXUSA4?lang=en&tab=discussion